# SQL:How to make condition mysql get p.id,count(l.id),count(c.id) from p,l,c?

Tags: mysql, sql

table post

```
------------------
   id   :   name
------------------
    1   :   a
    2   :   b
    3   :   a
------------------
```

table like

```
------------------
  like_id : id
------------------
    1     :  1
    2     :  1
    3     :  3
------------------
```

table comment

```
----------------------
   comment_id :  id
----------------------
       1      :   1
       2      :   2
       3      :   2
```

how to get `post.id,count(like.id),count(comment.id)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - "like" is a reserved word in SQL, used for regex matching, so you can't use that as a table name.  I've renamed this table "post_like" to stop this causing a syntax error.

Then it looks like a job for a [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html):

```
select post.id, 
  (select count(*) from post_like where post_like.id=post.id) like_count, 
  (select count(*) from comment where comment.id=post.id) comment_count
from
  post;
```